# why would I want a method that needs an instance?

Tags: static-methods

Why would I want a method that needs an instance? Why wouldn't I make all my methods static?

Comment: Given the brevity of the question I can somewhat rationalize the gross down voting. What I cannot rationalize is the down voting of a question that is pretty relevant to new programmers. Granted the question could have been asked a bit better I don't think this ultimately warrants 5 down votes.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you *not* want any state anywhere in your program?

Can you imagine if there were no String instances, and everything on String was static? How would you represent two distinct sequences of characters? Now apply the same logic to other code.

Fundamentally, OO languages are built around the idea of objects with state: one instance of `Book` isn't the same an another instance of `Book` - each `Book` instance encapsulates its name, author, publication date etc. How would you model that with only static methods, and no instances?

Of course you *could* make all your methods static and pass *in* a `Book` as the first parameter on each call that needed to use the state. Behind the scenes, something pretty much like that is already happening... except you've then lost polymorphism, so interfaces, abstract classes etc are useless. Not good.

Answer (score 2):

Because objects are state and behavior together, encapsulated into a single component.

If you have individual instances, it means they can each have private data that varies from instance to instance.

Static data and methods are shared at the class level.  Individual instances cannot have different static data.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods can't directly access the member variables within an object - they can only access static variables.

If you had a car class and a static data member like an integer in it, you could only ever have one car because you cant make multiple instances of cars and get multiple instances of that variable - you'd only ever have the single static one.

Every car can't have the same license plate number, thus ever car needs its own license plate variable.

The methods in the class that work with that variable need to be non-static to work on it directly then.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example of a "Car" class, you might have a method called "startCar()". Obviously, you want this method to interact only with a particular "instance" of a car and not be global to ALL your cars. Example in Java:

```
public class Car {
  public void startCar() {
    // code to start car
  }
}

public class MyProgram {
  public static void main(String[] Args) {
    Car myFord = new Car();
    Car myOpel = new Car();
    myCar.startCar; // starts the Car "myCar" and leaves "myOpel" alone
  }
}
```

It's also worth noting that Static Methods may not make use of Instance Variables of the class in which they are defined.